# Need help in the pagination of Web Scraping>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

As I'm very new to Python and the WebScraping. Can anyone please help in the pagination part of the website.

Website - https://www.dailydac.com/chapter-11-bankruptcy-alert-system/?cpage=1

I am able to scrape the data i.e. Company Name and Date of first page. Please help me in scraping data from multiple pages.

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.dailydac.com/chapter-11-bankruptcy-alert-system/?cpage=1')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)

# append the data to list
CompanyName=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/section/section/table/tbody/tr/td[4]')
Date=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/section/section/table/tbody/tr/td[1]')


Name = []
for i in range(len(CompanyName)):
     Name.append(CompanyName[i].text)

data = pd.DataFrame(Name)

Date_ = []
for i in range(len(Date)):
    Date_.append(Date[i].text)

data['Date_'] = Date
data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pay attention the first page url is

```
https://www.dailydac.com/chapter-11-bankruptcy-alert-system/?cpage=1
```

and if you want to `view page 2` content, then you would have to change value of `cpage`, and so on..

Below I have declared a variable `total_number_of_pages_to_scrape`  and set the value to `10`. You can change it if you want to any specific number.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
#driver.get("https://www.kraken.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
total_number_of_pages_to_scrape = 7
first_page = 1
Name = []
Date_ = []
for i in range(total_number_of_pages_to_scrape):
    driver.get(f'https://www.dailydac.com/chapter-11-bankruptcy-alert-system/?cpage={first_page}')
    if first_page == total_number_of_pages_to_scrape or first_page >= total_number_of_pages_to_scrape:
        break

    time.sleep(1)

    # append the data to list
    CompanyName = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/section/section/table/tbody/tr/td[4]')
    Date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/section/section/table/tbody/tr/td[1]')


    for i in range(len(CompanyName)):
        print(CompanyName[i].text)
        #Name.append(CompanyName[i].text)

    data = pd.DataFrame(Name)

    for i in range(len(Date)):
        print(Date[i].text)
        Date_.append(Date[i].text)

    data['Date_'] = Date
    data

    first_page = first_page + 1
```

**output :**

```
3rd Rock Logistics, LLC
3rd Rock Holdings, Inc.
Philippine Airlines, Inc.
Bennett Rosa, LLC
James David Theros
Mich's Maccs, LLC
RECON MEDICAL, LLC
James David Theros
Joseph Smart, Jr
RECON MEDICAL, LLC
U.S. Capital Investments LLC
County Investment L.P.
Massood Danesh Pajooh
Long Valley Real Estate LLC
Heilongjiang Barn, LLC
Verdant Holdings, LLC
Anthony Narancic
Specialty Orthopedic Group Tennessee, PLLC
Verdant Holdings, LLC
Affordable Concrete, LLC
San Diego Taco Company, Inc.
Long Valley Real Estate LLC
Sepideh Sally Cirino
Heilongjiang Barn, LLC
Terra Santa, Inc.
BESTHOST INN LLC
MOVIMIENTO PENTECOSTAL APOSTOLICO CRISTIANO, INCOR
Terra Santa, Inc.
Rickenbaker Gin, Inc.
Results Fitness, LLC
Roark & Associates LLC
Bexar County Properties, A Cal Ltd PSHIP
Jean Pierre Rwigema
Alibaba's Terrace Inc.
Scott Doren Spinner and Alicia Margarita Spinner
ARK Innovations Limited Liability Company
Thai Stk, Inc.
Di-Chem and Quality Technology, LLC
Alibaba's Terrace Inc.
Scott Doren Spinner and Alicia Margarita Spinner
SPL Partners LLC
A Thumbs Up Inc.
Di-Chem and Quality Technology, LLC
Rockworx, Inc.
Amado Amado Salon & Body Corp.
Dean A. Ditmar and Kelly E. Ditmar
SHURWEST, LLC
ARK Innovations Limited Liability Company
B N Empire, LLC
GBT Promotions LLC
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/03/2021
09/02/2021
09/02/2021
09/02/2021
09/02/2021
09/02/2021
09/02/2021
09/02/2021
09/02/2021
09/02/2021
09/02/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
09/01/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
SBG Universe Brands, LLC
SBG-Gaiam Holdings, LLC
Gaiam Americas, Inc.
Gaiam Brand Holdco, LLC
Joe's Holdings, LLC
LNT Brands, LLC
American Sporting Goods Corp.
The Basketball Marketing Company, Inc.
Galaxy Brands, LLC
SBG FM, LLC
Brand Matter, LLC
Heeling Sports Limited
William Rast Licensing, LLC
Sequential Licensing, Inc.
SQBG, Inc.
Itzhak Meir Shtark and Ayala Shtark
Heather Karen Therese Stanley-Christian
SQBG, Inc.
Sequential Brands Group, Inc.
Newstream Hotels and Hospitality, LLC
Newstream Hotel Partners-ABQ, LP
Sumak Kawsay LLC
Greg and Alice Logging, Inc
B N Empire, LLC
Itzhak Meir Shtark and Ayala Shtark
Heather Karen Therese Stanley-Christian
GGS Pizzeria, Inc.
Herman Alex Molina
GGS Pizzeria, Inc.
BL Santa Fe (Mezz), LLC
BL Santa Fe, LLC
Herman Alex Molina
St. Croix Custom Pools, L.L.C.
Linda Marie Kingsbury
Sid Boys Corp.
Phoenix Roofing & Construction FL, Inc.
Sid Boys Corp.
Kay W Eubanks
Tukhi Business Group, LLC
Roberto C. Hernandez
Roberto C. Hernandez
Michael Zollicoffer, MD PA
Kay W Eubanks
World Service West/LA Inflight Service Company LLC
John E Mayer
NESV Tennis, LLC
RHCSC Gainesville Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Gainesville Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Gainesville AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Gainesville AL Holdings LLC
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/31/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/30/2021
08/29/2021
08/28/2021
08/28/2021
08/28/2021
08/28/2021
08/27/2021
08/27/2021
08/27/2021
08/27/2021
08/27/2021
08/27/2021
08/27/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
Johnson + Associates Architects Inc.
NESV Swim, LLC
NESV Land East, LLC
NESV Land, LLC
NESV Hotel, LLC
NESV Field, LLC
NESV Ice, LLC
RHCSC Savannah AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Montgomery II Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Montgomery II AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Montgomery I Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Social Circle Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Social Circle AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Savannah Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Social Circle Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Social Circle AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Savannah Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Savannah AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Montgomery II Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Montgomery II AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Montgomery I Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Montgomery I AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Gainesville Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Gainesville AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Douglas Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Douglas AL Holdings LLC
RHCSC Columbus Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Columbus AL Holdings LLC
Regional Housing & Community Services Corporation
RHCSC Rome Health Holdings LLC
RHCSC Rome AL Holdings LLC
488 East 98 LLC
488 East 98 LLC
Brandy Houston Caldwell
22 Anchor, LLC
WSCE Corp.
WSCE Corp.
Brandy Houston Caldwell
E.L. Services, Inc.
Monterey Mountain Property Management, LLC
PSG Mortgage Lending Corp., a Delaware Corporation
22 Anchor, LLC
22 Anchor LLC
Jay Arthur Coakley, Sr.
The Odyssey at Paterson, LLC
TIX4TONIGHT, LLC
TIX CORPORATION
Bear Valley Ranch Market & Liquor Inc
Bear Valley Ranch Market & Liquor Inc
Thomas, Scott A.
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/26/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/25/2021
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
Nabil I Haddad and Peggy Haddad
HTP, Inc.
Brain Energy Holdings LLC
Scenic 30A Investments, LLC
Brain Energy Holdings LLC
Jay Arthur Coakley, Sr.
The Odyssey at Paterson, LLC
AA Varela Properties LLC.
JINZHENG GROUP (USA) LLC
Westmount Group, Inc.
Urquhart, LLC
Advanced Tissue, LLC
Alisha, LLC
Daniel R. Roubein MD PA
Daniel R. Roubein
AA Varela Properties LLC.
Brown Industries, Inc.
Broster JD LLC
HLH Timber Company LLC
W. E. McDonald & Son, LLC
Kenneth Olakunle Shobola
Bridgeport Health Care Realty Co.
Live Well Medical Centers Orlando LLC
Line Marie Martin
Live Well Medical Centers Orlando LLC
Silver Plaza, LLLP
Concrete Pavers Inc.
Line Marie Martin
JANA, LLC
Semoran Pines Phase II Condominium Association, In
Benson Property Investment Corp
Charles A. Izzo
Lynn Marie Lotz and Charles Edward Lotz
City Communications, Inc.
Treasures and Gems, Ltd
Dane Heating & Air Conditioning, Inc.
Semoran Pines Phase II Condominium Association, In
OLCAN III Properties LLC
One New Alliance, LLC
One New Alliance, LLC
Khosro V Farahani
The WOW Bar, LLC
Khosro V. Farahani
Palace Theater, LLC
Basic ESA, Inc. Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
Agua Libre Midstream LLC Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
Agua Libre Asset Co LLC Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
Agua Libre Holdco LLC Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
SCH Disposal, L.L.C. Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
Taylor Industries, LLC Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
08/24/2021
08/23/2021
08/23/2021
08/23/2021
08/23/2021
08/23/2021
08/23/2021
08/23/2021
08/20/2021
08/20/2021
08/20/2021
08/20/2021
08/20/2021
08/20/2021
08/20/2021
08/20/2021
08/19/2021
08/19/2021
08/19/2021
08/19/2021
08/19/2021
08/19/2021
08/19/2021
08/18/2021
08/18/2021
08/18/2021
08/18/2021
08/18/2021
08/18/2021
08/18/2021
08/18/2021
08/18/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
Basic Energy Services LP, LLC Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
Basic Energy Services GP, LLC Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
Indigo Injection #3, LLC Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
KVS Transportation, Inc. Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
C&J Well Services, Inc. Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
Basic Energy Services, L.P. Jointly Administered under 21-90002.
Joseph L Sanders
Ronald Lee Moore
MAIN STREET INVESTMENTS III, LLC.
C&C Construction and Management LLC
Basic ESA, Inc.
Agua Libre Midstream LLC
Agua Libre Asset Co LLC
Agua Libre Holdco LLC
SCH Disposal, L.L.C.
Taylor Industries, LLC
Basic Energy Services LP, LLC
Basic Energy Services GP, LLC
Indigo Injection #3, LLC
KVS Transportation, Inc.
C&J Well Services, Inc.
Basic Energy Services, Inc.
Basic Energy Services, L.P.
Mitchell K Cohen
MAIN STREET INVESTMENTS III, LLC.
Rosie's, LLC
Rosie's, LLC
Palace Theater, LLC
MAIN STREET INVESTMENTS III, LLC.
Deyo Transportation Services, LLC
Mitchell K Cohen
ALARMAS COMPUTARIZADAS, INC
Mitchell K Cohen
Anwarul Islam Chunnu
D&G Construction Dean Gonzalez, LLC
D&G Construction Dean Gonzalez LLC
D&G Construction Dean Gonzalez LLC
Shilo Inn, Warrenton, LLC
Shilo Inn, Bend, LLC
Shilo Inn, Warrenton, LLC
Shilo Inn, Bend, LLC
Synrgy Corp., a Nevada corporation
Acembly, Inc., a Delaware corporation
Synrgy Corp., a Nevada corporation
Acembly, Inc., a Delaware corporation
Wirta Hotels LLC
Damico's, LLC
Just Relax Massage and Spa, LLC
New Holland, LLC
New Holland, LLC
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/17/2021
08/16/2021
08/16/2021
08/16/2021
08/16/2021
08/16/2021
08/16/2021
08/16/2021
08/16/2021
08/16/2021
08/16/2021
08/14/2021
08/14/2021
08/14/2021
08/14/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
Wirta Hotels, LLC
Piz Family Deli, Inc.
DREAM DUFFEL, LLC
Regina Cargullo Ventura
Riverrock Recycling & Crushing, LLC
Eztopeliz, LLC
HPE Transportation LLC
CARE SHARE MANAGER CORP
1106 Montello LLC
Energy Enterprises USA Inc. dba Canopy Energy
Wasatch Co.
Wasatch Co.
EZTOPELIZ, LLC
HPE Transportation LLC
Vikram Srinivasan
Rickert Landscaping, Inc.
Moon Wholesale, Inc.
Moon Site Management, Inc.
Moon Nurseries, Inc.
Moon Landscaping, Inc.
Moon Group, Inc.
1106 Montello LLC
Moon Group, Inc.
Luis Arevalo
Luis Arevalo
Spectrum Link, Inc.
S & N Property, L.L.C.
SOCAL MRO LLC
Doris E Melendez
Bristol Properties LLC
Offcamber, LLC
Doris E Melendez
S & N Property, L.L.C.
Mulato Green Group, LLP
Mr. Camper, L.L.C. d/b/a Yogi Bear's Jellysto
Frank Bernarducci
Frank Bernarducci
May Contracting, Inc.
Gagik Sargsyan
Felisha S. Cottrell
926 Ventura Avenue LLC
Gagik Sargsyan
Travis Ryan Lee
EDUCATIONAL TECHNICAL COLLEGE INC
Innerline Engineering, Inc.
Secondwave Corporation
Secondwave Corporation
Piotr M Gawron
Innerline Engineering, Inc.
CHRISTINE LOUISE LAZNICKA and ANTHONY ROBERT LAZNICKA
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/13/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/12/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/11/2021
08/10/2021
08/10/2021
08/10/2021
08/10/2021
08/10/2021
08/10/2021
08/10/2021
08/10/2021
08/10/2021
08/09/2021
08/09/2021
08/09/2021
08/09/2021
```

Comment: Hi Sir, I tried this but this is only giving results that are on page 3.

Comment: Did you mean till 3 pages it could scrape ? Not after that ?

Comment: Each page has 50 results. I used total_number_of_pages_to_scrape = 4 and first_page = 1. But it gives me the only 50 results that are on page 3.

Comment: It should first scrape from first page and then continue till specified pages defined in the mentioned variable.

Comment: But it is not running like that. can you pleas help?

Comment: @AshishTalgotra : There was a minnor change in the code, see above I have updated. While the other answer has lot of code to scroll and then click the next element, this is a intelligent way to handle pagination.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is still giving 50 results only.

Comment: that is cause you have defined name list inside of the loop, it should be outside of for loop.

Comment: See above, I have tested the above code and getting the above output as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `next` option to move to next page and scrape the details.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.dailydac.com/chapter-11-bankruptcy-alert-system/?cpage=1")

details = []
for i in range(3): # for 1st 3 pages, increase the range to scrape more pages.
    tables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='filings-table']/tbody/tr") # Find individual rows 
    print(len(tables))
    for table in tables: # Extract details from all rows.
        company = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[4]").text # Extract Company name from that row
        date = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[1]").text # Extract date from that row
        details.append([company,date])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'next')]").click() # Find and click on next page.
    time.sleep(2)
print(len(details))
for i in range(len(details)):
    print(details[i])
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
50
50
50
150
['3rd Rock Logistics, LLC', '09/03/2021']
['3rd Rock Holdings, Inc.', '09/03/2021']
['Philippine Airlines, Inc.', '09/03/2021']
['Bennett Rosa, LLC', '09/03/2021']
['James David Theros', '09/03/2021']
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The url doesn't depend on javascript that's why no need to use selenium. You can do that only using pandas dataframe and requests and I have made pagination in start url and you can increase or decrease range of page numbers whatever you want.

My code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'}

urls = ["https://www.dailydac.com/chapter-11-bankruptcy-alert-system/?cpage="+str(x)+"" for x in range(1,10)]
for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

    wiki_table = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs = {"class":"filings-table"} )

    df = wiki_table[0]

    print(df)
```